# Removing noise after doing some preprocessing, so how come it fails? (OpenCV with Python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

So After some image preprocessing I have gotten an image which holds 5 contours

(**The image was resized for posting here in stackoverflow**):

[image]

I'd like to remove all "islands" except for the actual letter,
So at first I tried using cv2.erode and cv2.dilate with all kinds of kernels sizes and it didn't do the job, so I decided to remove by masking all contours except the largest one by this:

```
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(original, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I would expect according to the given image there would be 5 contours

```
areas = []

for contour in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    areas.append(area)

relevant_indexes = list(range(1, len(cnts))) 
relevant_indexes.remove(areas.index(max(areas)))
mask = numpy.zeros(eroded.shape).astype(eroded.dtype)
color = 255

for i in relevant_indexes:
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, cnts[i], color)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)

// Trying to mask out the noise
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(orifinal, mask)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", result)
```

But the mask I get is:

[image]

it's not what I would expect, and the **left down contour is missing**,
can someone PLEASE explain me what am I missing here? And what would be the correct approach for getting rid of those "isolated islands"?

Thank you all!

p.s
The original photo I'm working on:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

It sounds like you want to mask out the largest **connected component** ([cv-speak for "island"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)).

Here's an `opencv`/`python` script to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import console

# load image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread("img.png", 0)

# get all connected components
_, output, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, connectivity=4)

# get a list of areas for each group label
group_areas = stats[cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
# get the id of the group with the largest area (ignoring 0, which is the background id)
max_group_id = np.argmax(group_areas[1:]) + 1

# get max_group_id mask and save it as an image
max_group_id_mask = (output == max_group_id).astype(np.uint8) * 255
cv2.imwrite("output.png", max_group_id_mask)
```

**Result:**

Here's the result of the above script on your sample image:

[image]